# How to get the full object from firebase using a URL parameter

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create two views in an ionic app. But when I go from view 1 to view 2 with URL parameter I only get an empty object back from Firebase so my second view doesn't show anything. Totally lost here.

**Routing:**

```
    .state('app.trials', {
    url: "/trials",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: "templates/trials.html",
        controller: 'TrialsCtrl'
      }
    }
    })

  .state('app.trial', {
    url: "/trials/:trialId",
    views: {
      'menuContent' :{
        templateUrl: "templates/trial.html",
        controller: 'TrialCtrl'
      }
    }
    })
```

**View 1: /trials - shows all the trials, this is working.**

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="(trialId, trial) in trials | orderBy:'title'" href="#/app/trials/{{trialId}}">
{{trial.title}} | {{trialId}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Factory for view 1:**

```
.factory('Trial', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var trials = $firebase(ref.child('trials')).$asArray();

var Trial = {
all: trials,    
get: function (trialId) {
  return $firebase(ref.child('trials').child(trialId)).$asObject();
}
};

return Trial;
})
```

**Controller for view 1 (TrialsCtrl):**

```
.controller('TrialsCtrl', function ($scope, Trial) {
  $scope.trials = Trial.all;
  console.log($scope.trials);
})
```

**View 2: /trial - should show the trial that has been selected in /trials.**

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <h1>{{trial.title}}</h1>    
</ion-content>
```

**Controller for view 2 (TrialCtrl):**

```
.controller('TrialCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Trial) {
  $scope.trial = Trial.get($stateParams.trialId);
  console.log($scope.trial);
})
```

**Result from console in view 2:**

```
{$$conf: Object, $id: "3", $priority: null, $save: function, $loaded: function…}$$conf:   Objectbinding: fdestroyFn: function d(a){n.isDestroyed=!0,i.off("value",k),h=null,m(a||"destroyed")}inst: clisteners: Array[0]promise: Object__proto__: Object$id: "3"$priority: null$value: null__proto__: Object
```

So this object does not contain all the items in the trial object as requested by $stateParams.trialId...

How to get the full object and show the selected trial info in view 2?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

In view 2 /trials i was referring to {{trialId}} where I should have referred to {{trial.$id}}.

Changing this solved it.